# Adaptive Payments giving Exception on Web Server in c#

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on Delayed Chained Payments Module in Adaptive Payments in Paypal. I am Using AdaptivePaymentsCoreSdk for it and it is working fine on LocalHost as well as one web Server. All working is going Fine. But when I Deploy my application on another Server than On Service.Pay I am Getting an Exception. Exception is as Follows:-

```
 PayPal.Exception.ConnectionException: Invalid HTTP response The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute(String payLoad, HttpWebRequest httpRequest)
   at PayPal.APIService.MakeRequestUsing(IAPICallPreHandler apiCallHandler)
   at PayPal.BasePayPalService.Call(IAPICallPreHandler apiCallHandler)
   at PayPal.AdaptivePayments.AdaptivePaymentsService.Pay(PayRequest payRequest, String apiUserName)
   at PayPal.AdaptivePayments.AdaptivePaymentsService.Pay(PayRequest payRequest)
   at Payme101.Controllers.HomeController.Order_Pay(Order_Pay single) in  d:\Completed\Payme10\Payme101\Payme101\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 2404
```

My Code is As Follows:-

```
        PayRequest request = new PayRequest();
        RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
        ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList();

        request.requestEnvelope = requestEnvelope;

        Receiver receiver1 = new Receiver();
        receiver1.amount = 10;
        receiver1.email = "Primary Email ID";
        receiver1.primary = true;
        receiver1.invoiceId = str;

        Receiver receiver2 = new Receiver();
        receiver2.amount = 8;
        receiver2.email = SellerMail;
        receiver2.primary = false;
        receiver2.invoiceId = str;


        receiverList.receiver.Add(receiver1);
        receiverList.receiver.Add(receiver2);

        request.receiverList = receiverList;
        request.actionType = "PAY_PRIMARY";
        request.currencyCode = "USD";
        request.returnUrl = "http://ServerIP/Home/complete/?payKey=${payKey}";
        request.cancelUrl = "http://ServerIP/Home/cancel?payKey=${payKey}";

        //request.returnUrl = "http://localhost:1735/Home/complete/?payKey=${payKey}";
        //request.cancelUrl = "http://localhost:1735/Home/cancel?payKey=${payKey}";

        AdaptivePaymentsService service = null;
        PayResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> configurationMap = Configuration.GetAcctAndConfig();

            service = new AdaptivePaymentsService(configurationMap);

            response = service.Pay(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

          //Here I am getting Exception.
          return RedirectToAction("Order_Pay2", "Home", new { id = ex.ToString() });
        }

        Dictionary<string, string> responseValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string redirectUrl = null;


        if (!response.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILURE.ToString()) && !response.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILUREWITHWARNING.ToString()))
        {

            redirectUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=" + response.payKey;

            return Redirect(redirectUrl);

        }
```

Can Anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and What should i change to Remove this Exception And Make Payment Successfull.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Assuming your code and configuration is the same on other environments, there's not much to go on. Try enabling tracing to catch more details on the client/server communication here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx